# bind datagramsocket to inetaddress

Tags: java, sockets

When I use

```
   serverSocket = serverChannel.socket();
   serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 0));
```

for tcp-based sockets, I get given the address 192.168.0.2, but when I use udp:

```
serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 0));
```

I always get a null or 0.0.0.0 address binding. What is going on here exactly? I want the socket to be bound to 192.168.0.2 so that my other servers can communicate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Runs for me. What get you with this:

```
InetSocketAddress in = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.
                getLocalHost(), 0);
System.err.println(in);
serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(in);
```

What is your OS ?